# Sorting an array based on another array

Tags: python

I have two lists

A=[5,2,3,4,1]

B=[3,1,5]

I want to sort B using A such that the output reflects:
[5,3,1]

How can I implement this?

Comment: have you tried anything? Share the code first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use... but all depends on what you're after - there are other ways...

```
>>> a = [5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> b=  [3, 1, 5]
>>> sorted(b, key=a.index)
[5, 3, 1]
```

Or as @Manan has pointed out - you can in-place sort using `a.sort(...)`

Answer (score 4):

For an in place sort this should do it:

```
B.sort(key=A.index)
```

Otherwise you could do this (as per Jon Clements...):

```
BSorted = B.sorted(key=A.index)
```

How this works:

The `key` argument is a function (it's pretty common to use lambdas here...) The list is sorted according to the output of the function. The example below illustrates:

```
A = [{'a':100,'b':10},{'a':56,'b':100},{'a':90,'b':90}]
A.sort(key=lambda x:x['a']) 
print(A)
A.sort(key=lambda x:x['b']) 
print(A)
```

This outputs:

```
[{'a':56,'b':100},{'a':90,'b':90},{'a':100,'b':10}]
[{'a':100,'b':10},{'a':90,'b':90},{'a':56,'b':100}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your question is right, you want to do the following:

```
A = [5,2,3,4,1]
B = [3,1,5]
C = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] in B:
        C += [A[i]]

print C # [5, 3, 1]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or, that's written as `C = [el for el in A if el in B]` ?