# Pythonic way: Sort array items based on a class member and another array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have tried all I could imagine, but can't seem to arrive at a valid solution.

I need to sort an array of class objects based on their ID so that this ID is the same as in another list.

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self,i):
    self.i = i

itemList = [Item(2),Item(1),Item(4),Item(3)]
indexList = [3,1,2,4]
```

Expected output:

```
itemList_sorted = [Item(3), Item(1), Item(2), Item(4)]
```

I have seen a similar strongly downvoted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703612/sorting-an-array-based-on-another-array), but the solution did not help me, since I cannot use a function and need to compare a member of each item with an index in another array.

```
itemList.sort(key=lambda x: x.i - indexList.index) # Wrong
itemList.sort(key=indexList.index,cmp=lambda x,y: x.i==y) # Wrong
```

Is there a pythonic way to accomplish this without resorting to a C-like loop?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers address how to do the sort correctly—but I feel like you're taking the wrong approach here. Why not just build a new list instead of trying to sort the old one?

```
[next(y for y in itemList if y.i == x) for x in indexList]
```

Note that this should actually be faster than using `sort`, which has to search the `indexList` once for each of the *O(n log n)* comparisons.

Comment: This is a very pythonic solution!

Comment: The first option in @kojiro's answer is actually better for your specific example—but I'm assuming your `Item` class is actually more complex than this, making it impossible to just rebuild the items based off `indexList`.

Comment: yes, my class is a complex structure. I selected your answer because it allows for more flexibility and it is still very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Use `sorted(..., key)`:

```
sorted(itemList, key=lambda item: indexList.index(item.i))
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 2):

If you can assume that every index in indexlist is an `i` of your `Item`s, then you can just cheat and create them in order:

```
itemList = [Item(i) for i in indexList]
```

If that's not an option, you can sort:

```
itemList.sort(key=lambda x: indexList.index(x.i))
```